# How can I prevent a large input box to be stuttered when it is scrolled?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I have a large input box contains textboxes as input squares. The input box hierarchy is like `input box=15xjob box(J1,J2..)` and `job box=15x15 input square`.So an input box contains totaly `15x15x15=3375 input squares(textbox)`. The input box is inside a panel and it is horizontally scrollable because the input box is too large.

**Normal boxes:**

[image]

The problem is the boxes are stuttering and the lines are confused when the panel is scrolled and it takes time to recover like the image below.

**When scrolled:**

[image]

I think the panel can't refresh the screen fast enough because of the large number of squares and this problem happens as a result.

So how can I do the scroll in the panel without lagging?

Comment: You should think about grids

Comment: @SirRufo, what do you mean with the grids?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943680/populate-a-usercontrol-gridview-with-a-list-of-objects   Gives an example.  What are you going to do with all these input boxes after data is entered ?   There is very little you can do to get the scroll to be smooth there is just too much to render.  That is why DataGridViews were created.

Comment: @EJD, I am using this as a nxnxn matrix data. Can I get a similar appereance by using DataGridViews?

Comment: If I had to develop this I would have choosen a list control (J1..J15) and a grid control (K x M). So I had to manage 2 controls instead of 3k+ and it would be much more easier for the users to jump to any J level.

Comment: @AliTor I am pretty sure you could get it to look almost exactly the way you want it.  It is easy enough to try.  I would probably use a grid for each set of squares then add them all to a flow layout control.  This way it is not 1 huge grid.